# Get value of a component by id?

Tags: java, jsf

how can I get the value of a component, eg by id? Without backing bean?

This does not work:

```
<h:outputText value="test" id="testID" />
<h:outputText value="#{param[testID]}" />
```

Ty

Comment: This example makes no sense. should the first thing be an input component? Otherwise, the value would always be "test". Could you explain what you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
<h:outputText binding="#{test}" value="testValue"/>
<h:outputText value="#{test.value}" />
```

This should bind the first component to name "test", set its value to "testValue" and the second component refers to the first one's value.

Comment: Yes. That's what OP was asking for.

Comment: yes this really works! tyvm. Unfortunately my goal was to get the value of a text with param, like I edited above. Can I get this formatted text too by value somehow?

Comment: @membersound It would be fair to accept this answer because it solved the original problem.

Comment: I doubt you can. The formatting logic is in the renderer class. Also I suggest posting another question with a bigger picture of your problem.